# Не выходит связать 2 уже созданные таблицы OneToMany Doctrine

Tags: symfony2, orm, doctrine2

```
//Entity            
class News
    {     ....
             /**
             * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Iphpsandbox\PhotoBundle\Entity\Photo", mappedBy="news")
             */
            private $newsgallery;
    }
```

и

```
 //Entity
    class Photo
    {  ...
    /**
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\News", inversedBy="newsgallery")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="news_id", referencedColumnName="id")
         */
        private $news;

    }
```

Выводит вот:

> Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current
>   entity metadata.

Уже и чистил кеш и кеш метаданных, подскажите что это может быть?

Comment: Вы можете заставить это сделать: 1) `php app/console cache:clear`,2) `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`

Comment: Обновите весь vendor `composer updat`

Comment: Все это выполнял, не помогает(

Comment: Так может вы уже обновили базу ? Проверьте её.

Comment: проверил, колонка news_id отсутствует